# problems passing an object

Tags: objective-c

i know c passes by reference and im sure thats where my problem lies, but for the life of me i cannot figure this out.  (also there may be a framework or a more proper way of doing this, which im open to suggestions)

CrestronControllerValues is just a getter and setter class

i intialize and pass it in my app delegate:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"IPaddress", @"PortNumber", nil];

NSArray *objs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"10.8.30.111", @"41794", nil];

NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objs forKeys:keys];

[defaults registerDefaults:dict];



CrestronControllerValues *CCV = [[[CrestronControllerValues alloc]init]autorelease];
[CCV setIPID:3];
[CCV setIPaddress:[defaults stringForKey:@"IPaddress"]];
[CCV setPortNumber:[defaults stringForKey:@"PortNumber"]];

cClient = [[CrestronClient alloc] initWithCCV:CCV];
```

as you can see the last line passes it to another class
this is where my problem comes into play
if i try to use getipaddress or getportnumber i get bad access

```
- (id)initWithCCV:(CrestronControllerValues *)ccv
{
    [super init];

    CCV = [CrestronControllerValues alloc];
    CCV = ccv;

    port = [[ccv getPortNumber] intValue];
    ip = [ccv getIPaddress];

    NSLog(@"ip %@ ~ port %@", ip, port);

    return self;
}
```

i have tried multiple ways, including 
cClient.ccv = ccv   (as opposed to sending it with the init)
tried adding a getter for self so that it would be     cClient = [[CrestronClient alloc] initWithCCV:[CCV getSelf]];

Comment: i know bad access is usually trying to access/edit memory already allocated.  but wouldnt my app delegate release the object after passing it?  i have tried manually releasing it but that also didnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering `CCV` in your last snippet of code is an ivar, try this instead:

```
CCV = [ccv retain];
```

You don't need to allocate space for an existing object. Also, be careful with your init method pattern, you may want to take a look in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW4).

Comment: can you please elaborate on your init method pattern statement.  i read through the document u referenced but all the bullet points at the top are satisfied, so im not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: thought this fixed it but it was a typo on my side.

Comment: The most notable thing is that you aren't checking for initialization failure. That's what the standard `if (self = [super init]) { ...` does.

Comment: so ya, this isnt working, any other ideas to stop the crashing.  my most current code I added the self= super init & if(self)) & took away allocating CCV and added this.
    CCV =   [ccv retain];

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to store objects in `NSUserdefaults` is `[defaults synchronize]`. You're getting bad access because the objects you get from defaults are `nil`.

Check [NSUserDefaults Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: im looking into this because the answer below did fix the crashing but now my values dont pass correctly.  however i thought objective c always allow nil to be referenced, it just returns nil.  so i wouldnt think that would cause the crash.  either way like i said im still looking into this, thank you for the response

Comment: i did not have todo this for it to work.  not sure why, ive read the sync method and not really sure about when to implement this.  like i said it working, and all the tutorials i have read about NSUserDefaults shows a setup like mine.  (not saying ur wrong, just saying that it working and i dont understand how to use sync at this time)   thank you though

Answer (score 0):

Have IPaddress and PortNumber been synthesized? If you want to access those variables from another class, you'll need to make sure that in CrestronControllerValues.h, you declare the `@property` for each object and in your CrestronControllerValues.m, you `@synthesize IPaddress, PortNumber` unless you're otherwise explicitly declaring your getter and setter methods.

Answer (score 0):

here is the resulting code that works:

```
- (id)initWithCCV:(CrestronControllerValues *)ccv
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) 
    {
    socket = [[LXSocket alloc] init];

    [DDLog addLogger:[DDASLLogger sharedInstance]];
    [DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance]];
    sqliteLogger = [[FMDBLogger alloc] initWithLogDirectory:[self applicationFilesDirectory]];

    sqliteLogger.saveThreshold     = 500;
    sqliteLogger.saveInterval      = 60;               // 60 seconds
    sqliteLogger.maxAge            = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7; //  7 days
    sqliteLogger.deleteInterval    = 60 * 5;           //  5 minutes
    sqliteLogger.deleteOnEverySave = NO;

    [DDLog addLogger:sqliteLogger];

   // CCV = [CrestronControllerValues alloc];
    CCV = [ccv retain];
    port = [CCV getPortNumber];
    ip = [CCV getIPaddress];

    NSLog(@"ip %@ ~ port %@", ip, port );
    }
    return self;
}
```

and the sender method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [ConnectCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(command1ButtonPressed) 
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [SendJoin addTarget:self action:@selector(command3ButtonPressed) 
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [UpdateLog addTarget:self action:@selector(updateLogButtonPressed) 
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"IPaddress", @"PortNumber", nil];

    NSArray *objs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"10.8.30.111", @"41794", nil];

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objs forKeys:keys];

    [defaults registerDefaults:dict];


    CrestronControllerValues *CCV = [[CrestronControllerValues alloc]init];
    [CCV setIPID:3];
    [CCV setIPaddress:[defaults stringForKey:@"IPaddress"]];
    [CCV setPortNumber:[defaults stringForKey:@"PortNumber"]];

   // NSLog(@"ip from defaults %@   ~ ip from ccv %@",[defaults stringForKey:@"IPaddress"], [CCV getIPaddress] );


    cClient = [[CrestronClient alloc] initWithCCV:CCV];

    [CCV release];

    return YES;
}
```

another part of the problem was that port was an int
and trying to pass a nsstring to it caused crashing
but that [ccv retain] needs to be there